# Ruby: intelligent patch/update

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

After being blown away by the greatness of irb and rails console, I am loving the dynamical parts of the language more and more. Now, I wonder if it would be possible for a Ruby application to update itself on-the-fly (if the write permission allows it). Can a Ruby application fetch an update and refresh itself? I have seen this functionality a lot in Apple applications and I know updates and fixes are something you must anticipate for when deploying an application.

Thank you for your feedback, comments and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You can load a file that re-opens an existing class and alters behavior.  There are a few ways to get the new code, too.   Read it off disk, or have a socket that accepts connections and then eval the strings passed in.  Or use HTTP: http://www.neurogami.com/articles/The_year_of_living_dangerously/

BTW, there's some risk involved with doing thngs this way. :)

Comment: Better to shoot one eye out, than to write 'installers'. Thanks a bunch!